# How to check if a file exists in folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a class that creates acf + guttenberg blocks. It automatically includes style files and block scripts. But not for all blocks I need scripts. And when I delete the script file, there is an error in the console. How can I check for a file so that it does not include an empty file, but only when it is in the folder?

```js
                    acf_register_block(
                        [
                            'name'            => $slug,
                            'title'           => $file_headers['title'] ?: __('Unnamed Block:', 'bluegfx_dev') . ' ' . $slug,
                            'description'     => $file_headers['description'],
                            'category'        => $file_headers['category'] ?: 'formatting',
                            'icon'            => $file_headers['icon'],
                            'keywords'        => explode(' ', $file_headers['keywords']),
                            'supports'        => json_decode($file_headers['supports'], true),
                            'render_callback' => [$this, 'block_render_callback'],
                            'enqueue_style'   => get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $this->get_block_dir_path($slug) . 'style.css',
                            'enqueue_script'  => get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $this->get_block_dir_path($slug) . 'script.js',
                        ]
                    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file_exists()`:

```php
$script_file_path = get_template_directory() . '/' . $this->get_block_dir_path($slug) . 'script.js';

if (file_exists($script_file_path)) {
    $enqueue_script = get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $this->get_block_dir_path($slug) . 'script.js';
} else {
    $enqueue_script = '';
}

acf_register_block(
    [
        'name'            => $slug,
        'title'           => $file_headers['title'] ?: __('Unnamed Block:', 'bluegfx_dev') . ' ' . $slug,
        'description'     => $file_headers['description'],
        'category'        => $file_headers['category'] ?: 'formatting',
        'icon'            => $file_headers['icon'],
        'keywords'        => explode(' ', $file_headers['keywords']),
        'supports'        => json_decode($file_headers['supports'], true),
        'render_callback' => [$this, 'block_render_callback'],
        'enqueue_style'   => get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $this->get_block_dir_path($slug) . 'style.css',
        'enqueue_script'  => $enqueue_script,
    ]
);
```